# Url redirect not true

Tags: magento2, url

i have two url.

> **1 : abc.com**
>
> **2 : xyz.com**

I want when click `abc.com`, it load `abc.com` and when click `xyz.com`, it load `xyz.com`

When i click `xyz.com`, it load `abc.com` now. Please help me!

Comment: Can u please provide your code  ?..

Comment: Multi store site ???